# Geometry question involving a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

If $P$ is a point inside a circle, how do you find the shortest distance from $P$ to the circumference of the circle?

Comment: hint: symmetry dictates the one line you should be travelling along.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a hint without words ...

[image]

Comment: One image says more than 1000 words is an old saying. Quite neat.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

by triangle inequality, $~BD\geq AD-AB=AC-AB=BC$

Answer (score 0):

Connect the point $P$ with center of circle so that line will intersect the circle in the point that you ask for.